# How to automatically rebuild next.js app with a change in Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, vercel

I have an app that fetches data from Firestore. Is there a way to automatically trigger a redeploy in Vercel if there are any changes to the database?

Comment: What are you trying to do by redeploying on data change? Sure they do have an [API](https://vercel.com/docs/api#endpoints/deployments/create-a-new-deployment) to deploy but is that necessary?

Comment: @JoãoPedro did you check the Vercel's API reference that Dharmaraj mentioned? Does it answer your question?

Comment: Can you clarify why do you need to rebuild your Next.js app if something changes in the database? There might be other solutions to your issue depending on the reason why you need to do it.

Comment: It's a portfolio website. The database holds all the projects shown in the portfolio. I want to update the website every time a new project is added to the database.